# Looking for a “light” gwt framework with a rich-featured grid

Tags: gwt, datagridview

I'm looking for a gwt framework with a grid that can handle more than 500.000 rows and has features like filtering, sorting, basic events (click, double-click), multi selection, auto save, bulk save, etc. I was looking at sencha and smartGWT, but they seem a bit heavy.

Could you recommend anything?

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure GWT for your app. Here is an example of a DataGrid widget:

http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid

Note that there is no need to load all data into the browser. You can use an asynchronous data provider and offer different filtering, sorting, search, etc. options to your users. And you always show only the first 20/50/100 results to a user.

Comment: thanks Andrei. But I didn't see filtering / auto save options in the basic GWT grid. Does it exist there?

Comment: You can do whatever you need when a field is updated, including saving an updated value. For filtering, you use other widgets like a ListBox or TextBox, and then apply a filter to your data.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on PWT, we built this framework to be as lightweight as possible. 
All the features that you need are almost availabe.

But to be honest, I'am not sure that you must edit 500 000 rows on a single page, A so huge amount of data will cause memory and performance issues.

You can see the TableEditor on the sample Contacts Table : http://pwt.putnami.org/#!ContactsTable

Regards.